# Can only initialize Ad-hoc mode after restarting iwlwifi mod and network manager

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, networkmanager, network-interface

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.4 with network interface:

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 24
       serial: c8:f7:33:8f:d3:9c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.5.0-48-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=145.94.189.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:43 memory:d0400000-d0401fff
```

I have been trying to set up an Ad-hoc network on my laptop for some time now. I have already established that it works pretty much always at home, but not at work (I figure because there are more networks here).

Today I figured I'd replace the existing driver with one from the manufacturer [website](http://www.intel.com/support/wireless/wlan/sb/CS-034398.htm), even though they seemed to be exactly the same. (`iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode`, version 18.168.6.1) Unfortunately I didn't back up the old one.

With the 'new' driver I was suddenly able to set up a Ad-hoc network again, using either NetworkManager (0.9.4.0-0ubuntu3):

```
* ipv6 ignore
* 2.4 GHz (default)
* ipv4 manual    
* WEP 40/128 bit key (Hex or ASCII)
* MTU automatic
```

or commandline with `iwconfig` commands (With NetworkManager shutdown).

```
iwconfig wlan0 key 1234567890
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc
iwconfig wlan0 essid MyAdhoc
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

But here's the kicker, it fails to work after the NetworkManager establishes another connection (Infrastructure, WPA2).

When it fails using the NetworkManager these lines repeatedly show up in `/var/log/kern.log`:

```
Apr 23 11:01:57 *** kernel: [ 2424.593393] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S
Apr 23 11:01:57 *** kernel: [ 2424.600237] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Radio type=0x2-0x1-0x0
Apr 23 11:01:57 *** kernel: [ 2424.720967] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
```

and [`/var/log/syslog`](http://justpaste.it/f9zr) where I find the problem is with the wpa_supplicant:

```
Apr 29 17:13:39 *** wpa_supplicant[8406]: nl80211: Failed to set interface into IBSS mode
Apr 29 17:13:39 *** wpa_supplicant[8406]: Association request to the driver failed
```

Trying manually then results in (response to `iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc`):

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

I have tried disabling ipv6 as suggested [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html) among others to no avail.

Then I tried editing the GRUB file as suggested [here](http://namhuy.net/1419/disable-ipv6-ubuntu-linux-mint.html), which means booting with `ipv6.disable=1`. After reboot, it does eliminate the third line but it does not result in an Adhoc network.

If I want to establish a new Ad-hoc network to reset the iwlwifi mod (And if I use the NetworkManager I have to be fast enough to ensure that it doesn't start on another network first).

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be and how to resolve it?

Comment: I see you have two related questions, here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126099/ipv6-issue-setting-up-ad-hoc-network/126527#126527

Comment: Sorry for possibly stating the obvious but it looks like your problem is somehow related to the *iwlwifi* driver. The good thing is that iwlwifi is rather common among linux users. You might want to create a more precise description of your tests, or even a proper reproducer that would allow anyone to easily spot the bug you're hitting.

Comment: I incorporated the related question. I think it should be possible to reproduce the problem with the available information. If not, please let me know what I can do to help.

Comment: Could you possibly check it with a recent Fedora live CD/DVD/USB? If it works, you can check differences between those systems. When you're done, you might want to visit #nm on IRC freenode. Wifi problems reproduced with the current Fedora might be of interest to *dcbw*, wifi problems specific to Ubuntu/Debian releases might be of interest to *cyphermoce*, *mbiebl* or *tore*. If you're successful, don't forget to add the answer to stack exchange as well.